# Find all solutions in N of the following Diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

$(x^2 − y^2)z − y^3 = 0$

i divide by $z^3$ and look for rational solutions of the equation $A^2 − B^2 − B^3 = 0.$  The point $(A,B) = (0, 0)$ is a singular point, that is any line
through this point will meet the curve twice in $(0, 0)$. Now i wanna use Diophantus chord method using the lines
passing through $(0, 0)$ but i can't seem to pass this point

Comment: It seems like from $A^2-B^2-B^3=0$ you get $A^2=B^2(1+B)$, which has many solutions when $1+B$ is square... Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

At least for a nonvertical line $B=kA$ when plugged into 
$$A^2-B^2-B^3=0 \tag{1}$$ gives
$$A^2-k^2A^2-k^3A^3=0,$$
where here the double root corresponds to $A^2$ being a factor. After dividing by that and solving for $A$ one gets $A=(1-k^2)/k^3,$ and so also $B=kA=(1-k^2)/k^2.$ Finally a check reveals these values of $A,B$ satisfy $(1).$ So this is a parametrization of the solution set for rationals, which covers most points on the curve.

There of course would still be a lot of work to go from such a rational parametrization to finding all *positive integer* solutions to the starting equation.

*Added note:* For the starting equation $$(x^2-y^2)z-y^3=0, \tag{2}$$ if one puts the $k$ parameter in the above rational parametrization equal to $m/n,$ where we assume $0<m<n$ in order that we have $0<k<1,$ then we can work backwards and get a collection of positive integer solutions $(x,y,z)$ to equation $(2).$ The resulting expressions are
$$x=n(n^2-m^2),\ \ y=m(n^2-m^2),\ \ z=m^3.\tag{3}$$
Note that if given a positive integer solution to $(2)$ we multiply each of $x,y,z$ by some positive integer $k$ say, another solution results. So one could call a solution "primitive" provided the gcd of $x,y,z$ is $1$. In this sense, the remaining question is whether there are primitive solutions not included in the equations $(3).$ I've had some success so far on this, having shown at least that $z$ must be a cubic factor of $y^3.$

Comment: how'd you find all the integers?

Comment: @user241340 It isn't always the best move for solving integer equations to first find all rational solutions and then from that obtain integer solutions as special cases, or at least infinite families of integer solutions. (I haven't yet looked at this issue for your equation...) For some equations, there may be a clever thing to notice from the given equation which allows one to proceed and be sure not to miss any integer solutions. But this is more difficult than just getting the rational solutions, as I mentioned.

Comment: @user241340 I just put some more material at the end about the case of solutions with $x,y,z$ positive integers, to your starting equation before you introduced new variables $A,B.$ What it is consists of a parametrization in terms of two integers $m,n$ sort of like the usual one for Pythagorean triples. However I don't know at this point if all solutions are in the family I found here.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x^2-y^2)z-y^3=0$$

$$ x^2 z = y^2 (y + z) $$

Let $λ$ be the gcd of $x$ and $y$, then we have:

$$ x = λn, y=λm, (m, n) = 1$$

and the equation becomes:

$$ n^2 z = m^2 (λ m + z) $$

Then, because (m,n)=1, we must have: $z=m^2 ω$

$$ n^2 ω = (λ m + m^2 ω) $$

$$ n^2 ω = m (λ + m ω) $$

and again, because (m,n)=1, it must be: ω = m k

$$ n^2 k = (λ + m^2 k) $$

$$ (n^2 - m^2) k = λ $$

with the only restriction being: (m,n)=1

So, all the solutions are of the form:

$$ x = k n (n^2 - m^2) $$
  $$ y = k m (n^2 - m^2) $$
  $$ z = k m^3 $$

Comment: Good answer, and it proves we have expressed all the integer solutions. +1.